# how to get Query String value after ? sign in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following URL:

---

`https://localhost:44300/products/5746ba28804136004d060002?email=abc@gmail.com`

What I need is to get the value of email from the URL into a variable and then use it in a jQuery code:

`var email= "getthequerystringhere"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.search` contains any query string in the current page's URL. You can strip off the `?` at the beginning to get the part you want:

```
var queryString = window.location.search.replace(/^\?/, '');
```

If you already have the URL in a string, you can split it on the `?`:

```
var queryString = url.split('?', 2)[1] || '';
```

Once you have the query string, you can split it on `&` and then on `=` to get the particular parameter you're looking for:

```js
var url = 'https://localhost:44300/products/5746ba28804136004d060002?email=abc@gmail.com';
var queryString = url.split('?', 2)[1] || '';
// split query string into key/value pairs
var parameters = queryString
  .split('&')
  .map(function(param) {
    var pair = param.split('=', 2);

    return {
      name: decodeURIComponent(pair[0]),
      value: decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '')
    };
  });

// get the parameter with name "email" if it exists
var emailParam = parameters.filter(function(param) {
  return param.name === 'email';
})[0];

var email = emailParam ? emailParam.value : null;

console.log(email);
```

Comment: location.search is the best because it ignores the section of the URL before the `?` and also the hash fragment which follows the GET parameters (the part of the URL after `#` if it is present), so you can just get location.search and split using the & character, and you will get all GET parameters.

Comment: queryString variable contains `email=abc@gmail.com` i only want abc@gmail.com in variable

Comment: @AhmedJalal Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks allot @JLRishe

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var url = "https://localhost:44300/products/5746ba28804136004d060002?email=abc@gmail.com";
var email = url.split("?email=")[1];
```

Comment: `url.split("?")[1].split('=')[1];`

Comment: `url.split("=")[1];`